# marginTop was given a value of 30, this has no effect on headerStyle

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
defaultNavigationOptions:{
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.blue10: '',
            marginTop:30,
        },
    }
```

I was expecting that my header respect that margin but it was raising warning says "marginTop was given a value of 30, this has no effect on headerStyle."

Comment: What the version `react-navigation`?

Comment: react-navigation4

Answer (score 1):

For me *(react-navigation v5)* it was that my `screenOptions` *(called `defaultNavigationOptions` in react-navigation v4)* object used headerTitle property. So I changed mine from something like:

```
{
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.primary.main,
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight // <-- This here had no effect
    },
    headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
    headerTitle: ({ children }) => {
        const title = children.name;

        return (
            <ThisIsMyCustomHeader
                title={title}
                navigate={navigation.navigate}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

to something like:

```
{
    header: ({ children }) => {
        const title = children.name;

        return (
            <ThisIsMyCustomHeader
                title={title}
                navigate={navigation.navigate}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

So changed `headerTitle` to `header` and moved all the styling inside my `ThisIsMyCustomHeader` component. Maybe helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom header and give the style there. If that also doesn't work, try adding a view on top with `height:30` and `backgroundColor: 'transparent'`. It will give the same result.